# How to show input history in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Python, we can use `import readline` to make `raw_input()` accept `UP` key to show input history.

Is there any way to do the same thing in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Ruby's `readline` library, like so.

```
require "readline"
while buf = Readline.readline("> ", true)
  p buf
end
```

[Readline Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.8/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html)